# Prove $\exp (-i \phi(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}))=\cos \phi-i(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sin \phi$ using certain property

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, rotation, linear-algebra

I'd like to prove $$e^{-i \phi(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma})}=\cos \phi-i(\hat{n} \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sin \phi$$ using $$\sigma_{i} \sigma_{j}=\delta_{i j} I+i \varepsilon_{i j k} \sigma_{k},$$ where $\phi$ is a real constant, $\sigma_i$ are Pauli's matrixes and $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector. Every proof I've seen uses another procedures, such as Nakahara's *Quantum Computing: From Linear Algebra to Physical Realizations* (page 23). How could I do this?

Comment: Show your attempt and explain exactly where you are stuck. Asking for general help solving a specific problem is not supported on this site.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector

Comment: *another procedures* Another compared to what?

Comment: Compared to what I want to do, that is, using $\sigma_{i} \sigma_{j}=\delta_{i j} I+i \varepsilon_{i j k} \sigma_{k}$. I already solved my problem, thanks @G.Smith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relation dictates $(\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma})^2=I$, hence, for integer *m*,
$$
(-\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma})^{2m}=I, \qquad (-\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma})^{2m+1}= -\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}. 
$$
So, what is
$$
\exp \Bigl ( i\phi (-\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \Bigr )= \cos \Bigl ( i\phi (-\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \Bigr ) +i\sin \Bigl ( i\phi (-\hat{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) \Bigr ) ~~?
$$

Comment: Thank you! Finally I made a series expansion of the exponential and related it with what you told me, and arrived to the desired result!